# Deploy Custom Qt Widgets

Tags: qt, deployment, makefile, compilation

I try to deploy my custom widget with this [doc](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application#Installing_a_library) but when I compile only .h and dll are copied, .lib and .pdb are not:

This is my .pro when i configurer the copy directive

```
message(Building...)
QT          += widgets designer

PLUGIN_CLASS_NAME = QKWidgets

QTDIR_build {
    message(Qt Build)
    # This is only for the Qt build. Do not use externally. We mean it.
    PLUGIN_TYPE = designer
    load(qt_plugin)
    CONFIG += install_ok
} else {
    message(Public Build)
    # Public example:

    TARGET      = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
    CONFIG     += plugin debug_and_release
    TEMPLATE    = lib

    target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/designer
    #INSTALLS += target


    headersDataFiles.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/$$PLUGIN_CLASS_NAME/
    headersDataFiles.files = $$PWD/*.h
    #INSTALLS += headersDataFiles

    libraryFiles.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_LIBS]
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release): libraryFiles.files = $$OUT_PWD/debug/*.lib $$OUT_PWD/release/*.pdb
    CONFIG(release, debug|release): libraryFiles.files = $$OUT_PWD/release/*.lib

    INSTALLS += target headersDataFiles libraryFiles

    message(Lib dest: $$[QT_INSTALL_LIBS])
    message(Lib src: $$libraryFiles.files)

}

message(General Build)
```

**Edit:**
install_libraryFiles doesn't appear in Makefile

**Edit2:**

Output :

```
Project MESSAGE: Building...
Project MESSAGE: Public Build
Project MESSAGE: Lib dest: C:/Qt/Qt5.9.0/5.9.1/msvc2017_64/lib
Project MESSAGE: Lib src: C:/Users/SD/Documents/Studio/MyProject/Widgets/Build/Release/release/*.lib
Project MESSAGE: General Build
Project MESSAGE: Building...
Project MESSAGE: Public Build
Project MESSAGE: Lib dest: C:/Qt/Qt5.9.0/5.9.1/msvc2017_64/lib
Project MESSAGE: Lib src: C:/Users/SD/Documents/Studio/MyProject/Widgets/Build/Release/release/*.lib
Project MESSAGE: General Build
Project MESSAGE: Building...
Project MESSAGE: Public Build
Project MESSAGE: Lib dest: C:/Qt/Qt5.9.0/5.9.1/msvc2017_64/lib
Project MESSAGE: Lib src: C:/Users/SD/Documents/Studio/MyProject/Widgets/Build/Release/debug/*.lib C:/Users/SD/Documents/Studio/MyProject/Widgets/Build/Release/release/*.pdb
Project MESSAGE: General Build
```

Comment: What does "message(Lib src: $$libraryFiles.files)" prints? Can you show generated Makefile?

Comment: I edit my post. I understand why .lib are not copied. It's because the lib is not created at the good moment. when I launch qmake a second time, `libraryFiles` appear in my Makefile. An solution is : QMAKE_POST_LINK but i did'nt like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QMAKE_POST_LINK` solved my problem :

```
message(Building...)

QT          += widgets designer

PLUGIN_CLASS_NAME = QKWidgets

QTDIR_build {
    message(Qt Build)
    # This is only for the Qt build. Do not use externally. We mean it.
    PLUGIN_TYPE = designer
    load(qt_plugin)
    CONFIG += install_ok
} else {
    message(Public Build)
    # Public example:

    TARGET      = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
    CONFIG     += plugin debug_and_release
    TEMPLATE    = lib

    target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS]/designer
    INSTALLS += target # headersDataFiles libraryFiles


    headersDataFiles.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]/$$PLUGIN_CLASS_NAME/
    headersDataFiles.files = $$PWD/*.h

    libraryFiles.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_LIBS]
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release): libraryFiles.files = $$OUT_PWD/debug/*.lib $$OUT_PWD/debug/*.pdb
    CONFIG(release, debug|release): libraryFiles.files = $$OUT_PWD/release/*.lib

    win32 {
        # Copy *.lib
        DESTDIR_WIN = $$libraryFiles.path
        DESTDIR_WIN ~= s,/,\\,g
        FILES = $$libraryFiles.files
        FILES ~= s,/,\\,g

        for(FILE, FILES){
            QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cmd /c copy /y $${FILE} $${DESTDIR_WIN}$$escape_expand(\\n\\t))
        }

        # Copy *.h
        DESTDIR_WIN = $$headersDataFiles.path
        DESTDIR_WIN ~= s,/,\\,g
        FILES = $$headersDataFiles.files
        FILES ~= s,/,\\,g

        for(FILE, FILES){
            QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cmd /c copy /y $${FILE} $${DESTDIR_WIN}$$escape_expand(\\n\\t))
        }
    }
}
```